# Dynamically add a property with spread operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's take 2 objects and let's say I want to dynamically add a key to the first object with the value of the second, and to do this I want to use the spread operator.

```
let object1 = { key: 'myKey1', value:1 };
let object2 = { field: 'key', displaValue:'chiave' };
```

something like this:

```
let object3 = {...object1, [object2.displayValue)]: object1[object2.field] }
```

But unfortunately I have this result with the undefined key:

```
{key: "myKey1", value: 1, undefined: "myKey1"}
```

**Expected result:**

```
{key: "myKey1", value: 1, chiave: "myKey1"}
```

Comment: the problem is here `displaValue` (above) vs `displayValue` (below)

Comment: This will also work :)
let object3 = Object.assign({}, object1, {[object2.displaValue]: object1[object2.field]})